# Appcenter application pushing error form command line

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

I am working on Mobile app automation in VSTS using xamarin. Code was successfully executed on the local emulator, but while pushing to the appcenter from command line i am facing error `Test Chunking failed`.
I tried with admin privileges also, still i face issue can i know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any further information? At the moment it sounds like the same problem that appeared at the official Xamarin forums.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68616/test-chunking-failed-format-of-the-executable-exe-or-library-dll-is-invalid

Answer (score 0):

For me, what did the trick was to change the target framework of the Xamarin UI tests project to .Net Framework v4.6.1 (`net461`).